# Влияние <!doctype html> на тэг <br>

Tags: html

Заметил одну особенность. Есть нормальная страница с `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">`.
Продублировал страницу на другой проект, выставил уже `<!doctype html>` и дизайн повело! Все `<br>` как-то выросли по дикому! Т.е. если использовать `<br>`, то вроде нормально, но если использовать связку `<br><br>` интервал между строк увеличивается в примерно 1,5 раза от того, когда если не использовать `<!doctype html>`.
Считаю это некорректной интерпретацией тэга. Дизайн страдает, визуализация восприятия при чтении текста тоже.
С чем это может быть связано? И как этот "баг\не баг" обойти?

Comment: да всё таки маразм но управлять `<br>`  можно : https://jsfiddle.net/onc0t7e8/1/

Comment: @Дмытрык, исправил на интервал

Comment: @MaximLensky, про `line-height` я сразу подумал, но у меня его там ни где нет.

Comment: @MaximLensky, чем такие костыли, лучше уж просто убрать с заголовка `<!doctype html>` и жить спокойно. Просто стало любопытно. Не критично, но любопытно.

Comment: line-height даже если не написано в css но он всё равно есть  не зря же целый портянки reset.css существуют ...и это не костыль а выход из положения и если это требуется то приходится делать а вот doctype это тип документа который указывает в рамках которых должен быть проект т.е в html5 и более ранних версиях

Comment: Шаманов здесь нет, сайт в студию!

Comment: @Arcadiy, На древность контента на странице не обращайте внимания, так как заметил данный факт, он и стал интересен: http://krasnovosti.ru/documents/portfolio/portfolio_delphi_php.php (эта страница так себя ведёт) - может просто морально полностью устарела по коду?